# Angular 6 Data Sharing Service Subscribe not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, singleton, angular-components

I need to set Value in One Component (Component A) and Receive the Value in another Component (Component B). Component A and Component B are not Parent and Child.

I created a Shared Service to Share data between the 2 components. I'm able to set the value from Component B, but when I Subscribe to get the value in Component A, it's not being triggered.

Here is what I have tried:

I added Service in `@NgModule` `providers` array in `appmodule.ts` file so that it is available for all the components in the project.

**Service Code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocialService {

  constructor() { }

  private valueObs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

 public setValue(value: string):void {
     this.valueObs.next(value);
     this.getValue();
 }

 public getValue():Observable<string> {
     return this.valueObs;

 }

}
```

**Component B:** Setting value here

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componentb',
  templateUrl: './componentb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componentb.component.scss']
})


constructor(private socialService: SocialService, private http: HttpClient) {



}

 buttonClick()
 {

    this.socialService.setValue("linked successfully");
 }
```

**Component A:** Get Value Here

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componenta',
  templateUrl: './componenta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./componenta.component.scss']
})


constructor(private socialService: SocialService, private http: HttpClient) {

       this.socialService.getValue().subscribe(data=>{

    console.log('Trigger from ComponentB');
    console.log(data);

});

}
```

Trigger in ComponentA is being called when ComponentA is loaded with data being `null`. But it is not getting called when buttonClick is called from ComponentB.

**UPDATE**:

I figured out the problem, I should have phrased my question properly. 
When ComponentA and ComponentB are in the same Page(URL), the code works perfectly.

How do I send data between 2 components when they are in 2 different pages(URLS).

Example: User opens URL1 (Renders ComponentA) which has a button, User clicks on the Button and is redirected to URL2 (Renders ComponentB) in a new tab which has a button, when User clicks on the button, I need to pass some data to ComponentA and close URL2. I need to retrieve the data passed in ComponentB and use it in URL1. Is it possible using Services? If not, which approach should I follow?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as this should work.

Comment: You can do it on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @trichetriche, I have updated my question, could you please check.

Comment: @TusharWalzade could you guide me to any example code or tutorial?

Comment: @RafaelLima please see the update in my question.

Comment: maybe this could help https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Have you tried the ReplaySubject?

Comment: this worked for me in ionic4 as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You could effectively use `Subject` along with the router. So, **[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seyaz2)** is a live solution for your scenario using `Router` & `Subject`.

Your service will simply contain -

```
public setValue(value: string): void {
    this.valueObs.next(value);
}

public getValue(): Observable < string > {
    return this.valueObs;
}
```

Then, your `ComponentB` will contain -

```
buttonClick() {
    this.socialService.setValue("linked successfully");
    this.router.navigate(['/a']);
}
```

And, your `ComponentA`'s constructor will contain -

```
this.socialService.getValue().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataFromB = data;
    console.log('Trigger from ComponentB');
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need a ReplaySubject for that. Your component subscribing to the observable subscribes, after the value was emitted and hence the observable doesn't emit again, there is no value to get from that observable. A ReplaySubject takes care of giving the subscriber every emits which have taken place even before the subscription is done.

@Tushar Walzade solution works, because both components are within the app-component, so both observers are subscribing before the event was emitted. (The subscription takes place inside the constructor for both components, which is called before you click the button). But if you have a lazy loaded module for example, the one component would be created only on loading and then you would only get the data if you use a ReplaySubject or the rxjs operator publish or share

Have a look here:

[publish and share operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)
[subjects, behavior subjects and replay subjects](https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/)

Comment: You comment just saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to subscribe to `this.valueObs` not to method including this, As your variable `valueObs` is of observable type so you can directly subscribe to that like this -

```
constructor(private socialService: SocialService, private http: HttpClient) {

  this.socialService.getValue().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log('Trigger from ComponentB');
    console.log(data);
  });
  this.socialService.valueObs.subscribe(data=>{
    console.log('Trigger from ComponentB on Next called');
  });

}
```

Comment: `valueObs.subscribe` method is not called at all. Neither is `getValue().subscribe` method called.

Answer (score 0):

```
getValue method should return observable.

public getValue():Observable<string> {
     return this.valueObs.asObservable();
}
```

You can remove getValue() which is getting called in setValue() method.

**Component:**

```
this.socialService.getValue().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log('Trigger from ComponentB');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6uxlo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Tried this as well, not working. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: instead of calling in constructor() call inside ngOnInit

Comment: Updated stackblitz

Comment: If you want to share data between components in Tab. Better save the data in local storage and get in accessed in other places.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken what you need is either to `subsribe` or use `async` pipe in template for component a so you always get the latest value of the observable stream.

I've created a simple app to demonstrate this to you.

Let's say we have 2 routes, each of which renders the relevant component (a, b).

We use a service to share data between two components.

```js
Injectable()
export class MyService {

  private _data = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  setValue(value: string): void {
    this._data.next(value)
  }

  get data(): Observable<string> {
    return this._data;
  }

}
```

Then in component a we listen for changes of service's observable stream.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  template: `Component A <br> Data: <pre>{{data}}</pre>`,
})
export class AComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  data: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    this.myService.data.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
```

In component b we just edit data through service `setValue` method.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'b-component',
  template: `Component B <br> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="set data for component a" [(ngModel)]="modifiedData" (ngModelChange)="editServiceData($event)"/>`,
})
export class BComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  modifiedData;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  editServiceData(data: string) {
    this.myService.setValue(data)
  }
}
```

[Here's the snippet which demonstrates the above flow](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sebmzc)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your service. When you set the data, subject has already emitted the value. Do like this.

1. In your service make `BehaviorSubject` public and you don't need `getValue` method anymore.
2. In `ComponetA` where you receive the data from `CompoenetB`, make a subscription to the `BehaviorSubject` which is `valueObs`.

Modified Service class as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SocialService {

  public valueObs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  constructor() {}

  public setValue(value: string):void {
     this.valueObs.next(value);
     // this.getValue();
  }

 // public getValue():Observable<string> {
 //     return this.valueObs;
 // }
}
```